# Find pdf file links based on Google search API request

Tags: python, rest, google-search-api

I am trying to execute a Google search programmatically and find PDF files that match the search query. However, the following code does not find any links that include PDF in the link. When executing the query manually, the first link returned is a PDF document.

Can someone please guide me on what is incorrect in the code? I am wondering if the Google endpoint is not correct because when I use other URLs (like "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-extract-pdf-tables-in-python/"), a PDF link is found.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

parser = 'lxml'
query = 'HSBC most recent SEC 10-q report in pdf'
url = 'https://www.google.com/search'
params = {'q': query, 'num': 10}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status() 

# This comes as the first link when I Google manually "HSBC most recent SEC 10-q report in pdf"
# https://www.about.us.hsbc.com/-/media/us/en/investor-relations/hsbc-usa/220426-form-10-q-1q-2022.pdf

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    current_link = link.get('href')
    if current_link.endswith('pdf'):
        print('PDF found: ' + current_link)
```

Comment: Note that Google does not authorize people to scrape its website so it's probably not recommended to ask such things. Also, search results are ajax, so that is probably the reason to the inability to just scrape that page. I think that Google has proprietary API services that must be paid to do so.